# How to raise an exception and catch it after function execution complete?

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I have a line in my code that has the potential to raise an exception, i would like to handle this execption and continue execution.

```
def foo():
    #good code
    if thingThatHappensSometimes:
        raise CustomException
    #code i want to execute
    return resultIwant

def bar():
    resultIwant = None
    try:
        #good code
        resultIwant = foo()
    except CustomException:
        #code that should run if an exception was raised
    finally:
        print(resultIwant)
        print('All done!')
```

My issue here is that there are situations where foo will raise an exception but there is nothing in the code logic preventing it from generating a result for resultIwant. Currently, if I handle the exception in bar I will not reach the end of execution for foo but If I handle the exception in foo the exception will already be handled and I will not reach the except block in bar. is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: You can catch the error in foo, do something then reraise the error back to bar.

Comment: To expand on the last comment. Place the error into a variable in foo, keep executing the code, at the end of foo, if the variable has anything in it, raise the error else return the results.

Comment: It would be nice if you could make an minimal example of this cuase right now your foo fucntion will always aise the exception. you cant return a value and raise an exception its one or the other as either will cause the function to stop at that point and return the value or exception

Comment: in that case if the error is raised from the variable, in that case, I won't be returning results because the error will still be raised

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I will amend

Comment: if you want to return multiple values, you'll need to put them in a list or a tuple. you can't raise an error AND return a value. it's one or the other.

Comment: I want to check in a function of higher scope if an exception was raised in a lower scope. If i raise the exception then execution stops. If I handle the exception within then I won't know upon completion. The error is specifically difficult because it is happening in a sci-kit learn pipeline so there are 4 functions that feed their result directly into the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

raising an exception stops execution at this point, so you cannot both raise an exception and return a value. But you can return a `(value, exception_or_none)` tuple:

```
def foo():
    error = None    
    #good code
    if thingThatHappensSometimes:
        error = CustomException()
    #code i want to execute
    return resultIwant, error

def bar():
    #good code
    resultIwant, error = foo()
    if error: 
        #code that should run if an exception was raised
    print(resultIwant)
    print('All done!')
```